# Way around having to call es6 classes with new?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a function that takes classes and returns a class with a single class that can be extended, however I recently switched to the babel transpiler, and realized I'm not supposed to call the class constructors without new,

is there a way around this that would work in real es6 as well?

here's my multiple function

```
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols;

module.exports = function multiple(_classes){
    class MultipleClasses{}

    for (const {obj:_class} of iterateObject(_classes)){
        const prototypeChain = [];
        let prototype = _class.prototype;
        do{
            prototypeChain.push(prototype);
        }
        while((prototype = prototype.__proto__) !== null)
        prototypeChain.reverse();
        for (const prototype of prototypeChain){
            assignNonEnumerable(MultipleClasses.prototype, prototype);
        }
    }

    for (const {key, obj:_class} of iterateObject(_classes)){
        MultipleClasses.prototype[key] = _class.prototype.constructor;
    }

    return MultipleClasses;
}

function* iterateObject(obj){
    const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    for (const key of keys){
        yield {key, obj:obj[key]};
    }
}

function assignNonEnumerable(target, source){
    const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source);
    for (const key of keys){
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            enumerable:false,
            writable:true,
            configurable:true,
            value:source[key]
        });
    }
    const symbols = getOwnPropertySymbols(source);
    for (const symbol of symbols){
        Object.defineProperty(target, symbol, {
            enumerable:false,
            writable:true,
            configurable:true,
            value:source[symbol]
        }); 
    }
}
```

and to extend classes I use

```
class Player extends multiple({Physical, Circle}) {
    constructor(_x, _y, input){
        super();
        super.Physical(_x, _y)
        super.Circle(_x, _y, playerRadius);
...
```

is there a way to get super to call multiple functions or something?

Comment: [enhanced object literals](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals)? (you can set the prototype this way)

Comment: In what class did you learn that classes can return classes of classes containing a class? (In other words, your question isn't clear, and lacks some code)

Comment: If you're mixing a bunch of things together into a single thing, you should be mixing properties onto an existing class or extending an existing class. Mixing them together would break inheritance. Properly inheriting from subclasses is the reason classes work this way.

Comment: What's the point of using class syntax if you're not actually using them as classes though? This will all break the prototype chain. You might as well just use an object, `Object.create`, and `Object.assign`.

Comment: So that I can use super with functions from other classes that were defined using class syntax

Comment: Im not familiar with ES6 but maybe you could try `Circle.call(this, _x, _y, playerRadius)` and `Physical.call(this, _x, _y)` after  `super()`

Comment: So in other words, you want to generate some sort of mash-up between multiple classes and then use that as a base for a new class, to achieve some sort of multiple inheritance? And your problem is with calling the constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 100% required that class constructors in ES6 be called either via `new Constructor()` or via `super()`. There is no way around it, because this behavior is critical for JavaScript engines to be able to construct the proper type of object.

For your case, say Circle was

```
class Circle extends Array {}
```

your code will break because the object being created by

```
new Player()
```

will not be an array object. This applies to any native subclasses and is the reason that `new` is necessary.

If you want something to be a combination of many sets of functions, you will need to manually compose those functions together from standard objects.

Comment: thanks, I'll just write my base classes as functions then

Answer (score 0):

Although, new can be "dangerous", if you construct your classes with certain guards, you can still use classes. Yes, it's a bit quirky and the "Good Part"-ists turn their nose up at it, but I feel like classes are still a win overall.

```
class Player {
  constructor(/*args...*/) {
    if(!(this instanceof Player)) {
      return new Player(/*args...*/);
    }
  }
}

var player1 = Player("Spencer");
var player2 = new Player("Other guy")
```

Comment: True, the downside of this is you risk leaking resources by unexpectedly creating two copies of an object and then discarding a reference to one, especially once you start creating hierarchies of classes.

Comment: Can't actually do this, because it won't let me call without new, but I ended up moving the constructor to a private method and call it in the constructor / when an extends multiple class uses it

Comment: This doesn't work, it will always throw a `TypeError` in ES6.